# convert sqlprovider typed object to json string

Tags: mysql, f#, json.net, type-providers

I am trying without success to convert the type provided by the sqlprovider to json.

I have a method:

```
let getAll () =
   query {
      for c in db.MyDb.Table do
      select c
   }
```

then I call it with `Newtonsoft.Json` as such:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getAll ())
```

What I get is a string with a empty object: `[{}]`

If I create a type by hand, it works all right. It works as well if I am selecting a primitive type and a single attribute, like `c.something`.

I guess I am missing something basic (hopefully ;))

Comment: Can you try `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Array.ofSeq (getAll ()))` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that and was trying before to pipe the query with `|> Seq.toArray`. Both did not help, same result.

Comment: it "works" for me. That is under the conditions I have tested it. MS SQL, random table, getting all records from that table and running "your" getAll(). What version of Newtonsoft you got? I have 9.0.1...

Comment: 6.0.8 :S ... maybe that's the problem. I will check, thanks @HelgeReneUrholm

Comment: Updated the version to 9.0.1 and still the same issue. I am using MySQL though.

Comment: @JacekDominiak the version and database do not matter. If your query doesn't return anything, you won't get a Json string. Have you checked the *results* of calling `getAll()`? Did it return anything? Does the table contain any rows?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I forgot to ask for that earlier. I thought about it, but then again, somehow forgot in combination With the assumption that he had checked that part... I will bet you are right ;-)

Comment: Yes, the data is there, and when I am accessing a single value, for example with a map, I can get it no problem. I did a `printfn` of this query and this is what I get:
`[|FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity; FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity;
  FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity; FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity;
  FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity; FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity;
  FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity; FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity;|]`

The data is certainly there, now when I pass it though serialiser, nothing comes out of it, just series of `[{},{},{}]`. Any idea?

Comment: For now I wrote my own mapping types, which kind of defeats the purpose of type provider. I will keep digging, maybe I will be able to find something.

Comment: I think you can't avoid the mapping. It seems SqlTypeProvider returns this `SqlEntity` type that `JsonConvert` doesn't know about. If you extract the contents with ColumnValues or map it to some records than it's just some .Net object and it works. If there would be a way to directly map from SqlEntity object to an F# record that would be the best....

Comment: This seems relevant however I haven't tested it yet: https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/212. There is indeed a .MapTo method but little documentation so need to look at the source.

Comment: This is how I have it sorted by now. It kind of partially defeats the purpose of type provider if I have to specify the type when serialising it, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm not sure what the type provider for SqlServer generates. Will check, from the above comment   it seems  records. I don't mind wiring up some light-weight records and corresponding views, but better POCO-like access to the data would of course be better. As .MapTo() so far only appears in the API doc, I'll show an example in an answer  (as it's still much better then going in for the individual fields). And there might be a better way or some further improvement in SqlTypeProvider (which is at least being actively maintained). Btw, how would an ORM in C# deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

This type of usage was referred to in [Issue 212](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/212). Because the generated SqlEntity type is not something the Json serializer knows about, it won't be able to deal with it directly. One way to get around this is to define record types for the tables (which might not be pleasant for large tables). So for example:

```
type DataRec' = {
    DT:DateTime 
    ADAY:String 
    ID:System.Int64
    }

let qry = query { for row in table1 do
                  select row} |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.MapTo<DataRec'>())

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(qry |> Seq.toList)
```

> val it : string =
>   "[{"DT":"2016-09-27T00:00:00","ADAY":"Tuesday","ID":8},{"DT":"2016-09-26T00:00:00","ADAY":"Monday","ID":9},{"DT":"2016-09-25T00:00:00","ADAY":"Sunday","ID":10},{"DT":"2016-09-24T00:00:00","ADAY":"Saturday","ID":11},{"DT":"2016-09-27T00:00:00","ADAY":"Tuesday","ID":12},{"DT":"2016-09-24T00:00:00","ADAY":"Saturday","ID":13},{"DT":"2016-09-24T00:00:00","ADAY":"Saturday","ID":14},{"DT":"2016-09-23T00:00:00","ADAY":"Friday","ID":15},{"DT":"2016-09-25T00:00:00","ADAY":"Sunday","ID":16},{"DT":"2016-09-26T00:00:00","ADAY":"Monday","ID":17}]"

Comment: This is surely working, kind of defeats the purpose of type provider though. Thanks @s952163 for the research.